# Locked out of Android Vortex MID *permission denied with ADB

Tags: tablet, adb, factory-reset

Here's the back story:

I bought an used Android tablet. The guy said the power connector was broken so the tablet wont be charged. I took it apart and figured out the battery was dead. I have an adapter from the wall powering the device.

My problem:

There *was* a pattern lock. My daughter thought she would help me, and exhausted the 20 attempts, so it's now only giving me the option to use the Google account to unlock. I emailed the guy and he gave me his Google account info, but it didn't work on the tablet. It is the correct info for Gmail, as I tried it on my PC.

I have been trying to use ADB to get in to the tablet to no avail... I'm denied permission when I try to use `wipe_data`. I can't understand what the problem is.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe exploits like those used in [SuperOneClick](http://download.cnet.com/SuperOneClick/3000-2094_4-75447027.html) might help in this case?  Or [adb-based fastboot](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Fastboot)?

Comment: What model is this? Do you have a link to the product page at the manufacturer site? Does it have a working internet connection (3G)? There's 2-3 possible ways depending on the device: 1) If it has Internet, use Google Play to install an app to remote wipe. 2) If it has a recovery mode with wipe functionality, that's also a good way to go 3) Does it have 'fastboot' mode where you could also gain access via starting a crafted boot.img?

Comment: I think I know why the google account unlock/recovery procedure doesn't work: It need's a working internet connection. This tab only knows the guy's wifi (and maybe more like some hotspots or his friend's wifis). You'd need to mock one wifi (that the tablet already knows). Either drive to his location to get his wifi service or sadly: You have to ask him both ESSID + Passphrase and set up your home wifi accordingly (and  hope the tab connects). If successful, you could then  unlock it using the gmail method.

Comment: One more question. What doesn't work when trying to get into the device: 'adb shell' already or that 'wipe_data' command on the device' shell?

Comment: the data wipe command doesnt work. It relies with "access denied"
I am going to go to his house and hope I get a good wifi signal outside of his house. That makes perfect sense. I never thought it would be trying to match to online info...

Comment: Also, just for information's sake. I dont know the specific model and make, and I cant find the same one online anywhere. I'm relying on pictures which I know arent always accurate for the chinese websites.

I'm also going to look into this "crafted boot.img" I am brand new to android, thank you for your help. I'll keep you posted

Comment: Have you tried `adb reboot bootloader` > wipe from there?

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a bit late, but you can remove the lock by performing factory reset.
To do that:

1. Shut down the tablet
2. Hold volume up key and power button at the same time
3. Recovery boot menu will open. With volume keys select wipe data and press power button.
   The tablet will do a factory reset, all data will be lost and pattern lock will be removed.

You probably got denied permission on ADB because debug mode wasn't on.